# why are some images not display in IE8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

in my website bannner images are not displayed in IE8 , red cross is appeared in place of image, but it works properly in mozilla and chrome. I googled for that and I tried also those suggestion but its not working.

Comment: Is the image CMYK? IE8 won't show those.

Comment: Guess I should answer that so you can accept it, if it's right!

Answer (score 1):

IE8 won't show jpegs that are CMYK. Make sure you change them to be RGB using an image editor.

If you have ImageMagick installed (if not, get it!) you can use:

```
identify -verbose yourImage.jpg
```

to find out everything about the file.

Again, using ImageMagick you can run:

```
convert cmyk_image.jpg -colorspace rgb rgb_image.jpg
```

to convert into rgb – be warned, sometimes the colours might look different so don't assume it will be OK without checking.

If you want the file to overwrite the original use:

```
mogrify -colorspace rgb cmyk_image.jpg
```